# how to change color in a container after a condition flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

> I want to display my container in another color after the "unlock".
> how can I do this? when the challenge is accepted it displays as
> deeppurple. after the unlock it should display as yellow.

```
child: Container(
                      height: 70, //Size.width * 2,
                      width: (Size.width - 70) / 4,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color:  ch[index]['isAccepted'] == 0 ?
                        textWhite.withOpacity(0.3) : Colors.deepPurple,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Center(
                            child: ch[index]['status'] == "unlocked"
                                ? Image.network(ch[index]['image'])
                                : Image.asset("assets/images/lock.png")),
                        
                      ),
                    ),
```

[image]

the first box was already unlocked
the second box only accepted
the third box without doing any accept or unlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method. That will make your code more readable when the conditions get more complex:

```
Color getCorrectColor(Map<String, dynamic> statusMap) {
  if (statusMap['status'] == "unlocked") {
    return Colors.yellow;
  }
  if (statusMap['isAccepted'] == 0) {
    return textWhite.withOpacity(0.3);
  }
  return Colors.deepPurple;
}
```

and instead do:

```
BoxDecoration(
  color:  getCorrectColor(ch[index]),
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
)
```